# How to autobox a primitive literal?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Previously in Objective-C, I would be able to do something like:

```
NSInteger count = 100;
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count: %@", @(count)];
```

Objective-C had introduced the concept of autoboxing primitive literals so I didn't have to deal with `%d`, `%ld`, etc. It'll automatically convert the primitive literal into an `NSObject` which the formatter to parse as a `%@`.

In swift, is there something similar we can do?

```
let count: Int = 100
let text = String.init(format: "count of %@", count)
```

The above crashes because `count` is not a pointer to an object.

I know I can do inline parameter injection like:

```
let text = "count of \(count)"
```

But due to localization purposes, localizing the string format needs to happen before updating the parameters, which the code immediately above can't do.

Comment: FYI - that's not at all the typical solution in Objective-C. Most people would use: `NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"count: %ld", (long)count];`.

Comment: The `%@` format specifier specifically targets Objective-C objects. Since Swifts native `Int` is not (no longer) implicitly bridged to an Obj-C object (`NSNumber`), the format specifier cannot be applied to such a native type. The reason your own workaround works is that `String` is still bridged to `NSString`. Another workaround is to convert your `Int` instance to `NSNumber` prior to parsing it with `%@`: `let text = String.init(format: "count of %@", NSNumber(value: count))`.

Comment: So is your problem that you need to be able to update count dynamically?

Comment: More specifically, why can't you localize the string format with inline parameter injection?

Comment: Every number that is going to be displayed to the user should be formatted using `NSNumberFormatter`.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ This is why localization doesn't work with inline parameter injection: http://www.openradar.me/20732896 -- it substitutes the parameters first before looking up the localized string.

Answer (score 1):

Use Foundation types and bridge to `NSNumber`?

```
let count1: NSNumber = 100 // 100
let count2: NSNumber = 0.0 // 0
let count3: NSNumber = 2.73 // 2.73
let text = String(format: "count of %@ %@ %@", count1, count2, count3) // "count of 100 0 2.73"
```

That's really what "autoboxing" does, it wraps a primitive type in an Objective-C `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Yah, I had considered wrapping it inside a `NSNumber`, but was curious if swift had some syntax that automatically did that for me. From what others are saying, it doesn't seem like there is.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't quite answer the question, but I worked around the problem by wrapping my parameter with `String(…)`, e.g.

```
let count: Int = 100
let text = String.init(format: "count of %@", String(count))
```

**Update**: an equivalent implementation to the above:

```
let count: Int = 100
let text = String.init(format: "count of %@", "\(count)")
```

Comment: Be careful with String interpolation, as it may return a different result than the String initializer (it returns the object's `description`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually accomplish this:  I just use a placeholder for the localization and swap it out after.  So my strings files would look like this:

```
//English
"Could not read <name>" = "Could not read <name>."
//Spanish
"Could not read <name>" = "No puede leer <name>."
```

And my code would look like this:

```
//assume you have a fileName variable
var localizedString = NSLocalizedString("Error reading <name>", comment: "Error message when an object could not be read.")
localizedString = localizedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "<name>" with: fileName)
```

Instead of using an already-localized `fileName`, as I have in my example above, you could easily swap the placeholder for something like `"\(count)"`.  Just make sure that you localize the dropped-in value so that it displays nicely when put together with the text.